# MySQL Union and Duplicates

Tags: mysql

This is a short snippet of a very long query with about 6 unions but they are all roughly the same logic:

```
(SELECT cr.id, cr.price, cd.times, cd.name, cr.set_rarity, cd.type, cd.currentPrice_tcg 
FROM card_sets_rarity cr
JOIN card_database cd
ON cr.id = cd.id
WHERE cr.set_rarity = 'Common'
AND cr.set_name = 'Dark Beginning 1'
AND cd.type = 'Spell Card'
GROUP BY cd.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)

UNION 

(SELECT cr.id, cr.price, cd.times, cd.name, cr.set_rarity, cd.type, cd.currentPrice_tcg 
FROM card_sets_rarity cr
JOIN card_database cd
ON cr.id = cd.id
WHERE cr.set_rarity = ?
AND cr.set_name = 'Dark Beginning 1'
AND cd.type = 'Spell Card'
GROUP BY cd.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
```

In the second query, the rarity is set depending on chance calculated in PHP. So I get a random number and if it's under 5 the rarity is "`Rare`" but if it's over 5 the rarity is "`Common`".

The problem now arises when it gets "`Common`", sometimes the query will choose a common that was already selected in the first query (**I don't want duplicates**).
Is it possible to work around this? How can I make it so that it avoids picking a duplicate which will get stripped by the `UNION`?

MySQL Version 5.7.30

DB Fiddle Example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7wFDnYuVPt15qPorQvemrw/4

**Further explanation**:

What I need: Always return 3 unique rows using this `UNION`.

Problem: It sometimes returns 2 rows as the second query can end up picking a row that was already chosen in the first query.

`UNION ALL` will not work as it will return duplicates.

Comment: It's not a duplicate if any of the selected columns differ.

Comment: Right..but there is a chance for it to get duplicates? There's a chance that the second query gets "Common" and picks a row that was already selected in the first query, thus giving me a duplicate and stripping it out.

Comment: Sample data would be very helpful here.

Comment: Update your sample data with this fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7wFDnYuVPt15qPorQvemrw/0 then click 'Update'. After that [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62039737/edit) and include the updated fiddle link.

Comment: is your goal to generate a random starting hand of Yu-Gi-Oh with an appropriate mix of rare and common cards ? I dont play that game but I know very well MTG and I have created similar online systems for it, so i can help

Comment: tcadidot0 I'll have it updated soon! Thomas G, it's for my pack opening simulator :)

Comment: ok so you want to generate your own "booster packs" like you would have purchased them? and so each pack has to contain a fixed amount of rares and commons, but picked up randomly from your card database for a specific extension... right?

Comment: `UNION` already removes duplicates. Please be more specific in what you mean by "duplicates".

Comment: I've added a db-fiddle example, keep hitting run and you'll eventually get 2 results instead of 3 which is what is happening to me.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel, sorry my OP wasn't clear. I've updated it now. How can I make it so that the second query avoids picking something that was selected from the first query which will get stripped by the union?

Comment: @GenesisBits it is normal with your current query state in db-fiddle that it returns sometimes 2 and sometimes 3 rows, because you doan UNION over 2 queries that select the same data. Thus if one of the cards are in both queries, one of them is removed. You can do an UNION ALL in this case. But you would better to clearly explain what you want to do or if my last hypothesis above was right, and we will come with a solution

Comment: I've added a further explanation. What I need: Always return 3 unique rows using this UNION. UNION ALL will not work as it returns duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
-- your query
(SELECT cr.id, cr.price, cd.times, cd.name, cr.set_rarity, cd.type, cd.currentPrice_tcg 
FROM card_sets_rarity cr
JOIN card_database cd
ON cr.id = cd.id
WHERE cr.set_rarity = 'Common'
AND cr.set_name = 'Dark Beginning 1'
AND cd.type = 'Spell Card'
GROUP BY cd.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)

UNION 

(SELECT cr.id, cr.price, cd.times, cd.name, cr.set_rarity, cd.type, cd.currentPrice_tcg 
FROM card_sets_rarity cr
JOIN card_database cd
ON cr.id = cd.id
WHERE cr.set_rarity = ?
AND cr.set_name = 'Dark Beginning 1'
AND cd.type = 'Spell Card'
GROUP BY cd.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3)  -- LIMIT enlarged to 3
-- end of your query
     ) subquery
ORDER BY set_rarity != 'Common', RAND() LIMIT 3
```

If parameter is not 'Common' then you'll get 2 'Common' rows and 3 non-'Common' row from subquery, sorting will posess 'Common' rows first and 3rd will be random of 3 non-'Common' rows.

If parameter is 'Common' then you'll get 3-5 rows in subquery and select 3 random from them.

---

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7wFDnYuVPt15qPorQvemrw/5) (based on OP's fiddle) - always returns 3 different records (if exists in source table, of course).

Comment: Thanks for this! I've tested and it does exactly what I need! Thanks for the detailed answer and understanding my ramblings.

Answer (score 3):

I would change the variable parts of the query. Right now your parameter is `set_rarity` (`cr.set_rarity = ?`). I would let it be fixed to "Rare", but make the LIMITs variable.

Assuming you have something like this in your PHP code:

```
if ($randomNumber > 5) {
    $rarityParam = 'Common';
} else {
    $rarityParam = 'Rare';
}
```

I would change it to:

```
$commonLimitParam = 2;
$rareLimitParam = 0;

if ($randomNumber > 5) {
    $commonLimitParam += 1;
} else {
    $rareLimitParam   += 1;
}
```

and bind the above parameters into tghe following query:

```
(SELECT cr.id, cr.price, cd.times, cd.name, cr.set_rarity, cd.type, cd.currentPrice_tcg 
FROM card_sets_rarity cr
JOIN card_database cd
ON cr.id = cd.id
WHERE cr.set_rarity = 'Common'
AND cr.set_name = 'Dark Beginning 1'
AND cd.type = 'Spell Card'
GROUP BY cd.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?)

UNION 

(SELECT cr.id, cr.price, cd.times, cd.name, cr.set_rarity, cd.type, cd.currentPrice_tcg 
FROM card_sets_rarity cr
JOIN card_database cd
ON cr.id = cd.id
WHERE cr.set_rarity = 'Rare'
AND cr.set_name = 'Dark Beginning 1'
AND cd.type = 'Spell Card'
GROUP BY cd.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?)
```

Comment: This is actually quite a clever way of doing it! I wouldn't have thought of doing it through LIMIT like that. I'm going to test this too. Thanks!